# Maintaining interpolation in the image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this 3x3 matrix of values which I am visualizing in a interpolated form using `plt.imshow(data, interpolation = 'spline16')` and I am getting the following image as output:

[image: Interpolated image]

Now, I want to save this image as it is in the interpolated form, but the issue is that `plt.imsave()` has no parameter for interpolation. So the image is being saved in this form:

[image: Normal Image]

So, my question is, How do I save the image in my python script in the interpolated form?

Comment: How about [savefig](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)?

Comment: Actually I can't see a interpolating feature with savefig either, I think my real question is, How can I permanently set a interpolation for my Image as when I use `plt.imshow`, it is only for visualization(temporary).

Comment: The idea is of course to set the interpolation in `imshow(data, interpolation=...)` and then `savefig` the thus obtained image. To get similiar output as with `imsave` you would need to remove the axis, spines and ticklabels. That is googable.

Answer (score 2):

This will plot the matrix using interpolation and save it to a file:

```
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto')
plt.savefig('outputName.png')
```

One thing to note is that this will save it with axes and a border. If you want it without axes and borders add:

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('outputName.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
```